# Attach file existing on FTP server to mail in C# .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, ftp, email-attachments

I am trying to attach a file saved on an FTP Server to a SMTP mail message.

```
mail.Body = body;

System.Net.Mail.Attachment attachment;

attachment = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(Server.MapPath("Documents/quote.pdf"));
mail.Attachments.Add(attachment);
SmtpServer.Send(mail);
```

However, finding the attachment seems to trouble, due to an authentication issue. I am not quite sure if I should use a RequestStream and get the response, or if there is a way to authenticate the path for reading and adding the attachment to the email. The issue with the RequestStream is that I cant get the filename, which is what I need to add as a parameter when creating an attachment.
Any advise? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What `RequestStream` are you referring to? What do you mean by *"cant get the filename"*? If you want to retrieve a file from FTP, you have to know it's name. After all, the name is in your code!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `FtpWebRequest` to obtain a `Stream` referring to a file contents on an FTP server. And then use an [overload of `Attachment` constructor that takes a `Stream`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.attachment.-ctor#system-net-mail-attachment-ctor(system-io-stream-system-string)).

```
const string filename = "quote.pdf";

var url = "ftp://ftp.example.com/remote/path/" + filename;
FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;

Stream contentStream = request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream();
Attachment attachment = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(contentStream, filename);
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks a million!

Comment: Apologies. New to this. Last time I clicked the upvoting icon, I didnt have enough reputation lol.